# after delete a cloud function it still in gcf-sources

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I deployed two firebase cloud functions then I deleted one of them using firebase CLI as the docs said, but I can still see it in the gcf-sources in Google cloud. Why it is still there? is it safe to delete it manually? or it will be deleted by the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloud Functions creates Google Cloud Storage (GCS) buckets for each region in each project in which you deploy/create Cloud Functions.

The GCS Buckets are named `gcf-source-${projectNumber}-${region}` where `projectNumber` and `region` are replaced by values.

The Buckets contain copies of the files used for each Cloud Function deployment.

If you're confident you will not use the Cloud Functions and that you no longer need copies of these files in GCS, though it's specifically discouraged (see the `README.md` in the Bucket's root), you can delete the files. But GCS object storage is **cheap** and the cost to you in retaining these files will be very low.

Comment: thank you for your answer. any idea why they don't delete it when I delete it from FIrebase CLI?

Comment: I think it would be reasonable for there to be a flag that the user could set when deleting to tidy up artifacts. You could file an issue against Google's public [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)